# Is mapPolyline a property of the NMARoute?

Tags: ios, here-api

[The NMARoute documentation](https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMARoute.html) says that there's a non-null `mapPolyline` property of NMARoute that contains a polyline representation of the route, but it appears to be missing:

[image]

Is this documentation outdated, is it a bug, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Kindly provide your ios version and mobile details inorder to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The NMAMapPolyline representation of the route. This property is deprecated for premium sdk as of NMA SDK 3.3. This is replaced by geometry.NMAMapPolyline may be instantiated from geometry via "mapPolylineWithVertices:".

However for Starter SDK the functionality exist. Please check and update which SDK you are trying to use.

Comment: OK thanks. Is it possible to change the line thickness of a premium NMAMapRoute when it's displayed on a premium NMAMapView?